How may I audit unencrypted network traffic on macOS device?
I'm doing day-to-day activities on a MacBook connected to a coffee shop wifi network, which is an 'Unsecured Network...':

When clicked on:

I'm only visiting https websites, but I know websites aren't the only way the apps/device are interacting over the unsecured network. So I wonder..
Question
Is there a macOS feature, macOS app, or command line tool I can audit all network traffic over, say, an hour or a day, and let me filter on any that is unencrypted, so I can inspect it and determine if it's a risk.

I would start with whichever of the proxy solutions listed here balances with your effort needed to learn and set up with any cost for a license.
My preference is wireshark and Charles proxy.

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallOSXInstall.html
https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/installation/

I’m not aware of macOS tools that aggregate network requests unless you consider the App Privacy Report suitable level of “auditing”.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102188

